# The correct spelling of the last name Щучинский

Tags: власні-назви

What is the correct spelling for the last name *Щучинский*?

Answer (score 0):

Олександр ЩУЧИНСЬКИЙ, Рівне (https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/cuspilstvo/chotiri-vladi-i-odna-dolya)

[Щучинський район](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A9%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD) — адміністративна одиниця Білорусі, Гродненська область.